# Show geotiff format images

Tags: openlayers, here-api, openlayers-5

I am new to Here Api, until now I was just using the HERE Map Tile API in a OpenLayers Maps.
I have several .tiff format images, and I wanted to show these images at their coordinates on the front-end using angular 8 and OpenLayers.[Like the following image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us65M.png)

I was just wondering if HERE Studio or HERE API can help me to solve this issue?

Can you tell me what is the best approach ? Is there any examples ?

Comment: Since most browsers don't display tif you would need some third party utilities such as https://eox.at/2018/01/visualizing-geotiff-tiles-with-openlayers/ or maybe you could try using https://geotiffjs.github.io/ in conjunction with `ol.source.ImageCanvas`?  Or look into server-side utilities https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212503/adding-geotiff-to-openlayers-3

Comment: @Paulo what product? SDK or Javascript API?

Answer (score 0):

Geotiff can not add to map directly. You can convert to tile server (XYZ) and then you can add to map.

Another solution is that you can use '***geotiff.js***' library where can be linked [this link](https://geotiffjs.github.io/).